# Iterate through a json array mysql 8

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-8.0

I have the fiollowing table schema with a JSON field,

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
      `stats` json NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

I have inserted the following,

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES('[{"days": 15, "percentage": 50},{"days": 5, "percentage": 100}]');
```

What i would like to do now is iterate through this and return the percentage for a given day or just display each key pair value separately. How do i go about it ?

I found the following query from [here](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=94549), and i tried to make it work for my purpose but the output is not as expected. Ideally I would like to do it in a query like this without using stored procedures or anything else,

```
select stats, i, concat('stats', element) from `test`, json_table(stats, '$[*]' columns (i for ordinality, element varchar(100) path '$')) jt;
```

So the output would be 50 if 15 was given as the day.

```
   day percentage
    15  50
```

Or the following result when iterating without filtering for a particluar day

```
   day percentage
    15  50
    5   100
```

Heres the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=02b831528dfcc49677e8db002253dbd8) with my attempt

The keys would be unique in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT stats, i, days, percentage
FROM test, 
     JSON_TABLE(stats, 
                '$[*]' COLUMNS (i FOR ORDINALITY, 
                                days VARCHAR(100) PATH '$.days', 
                                percentage VARCHAR(100) PATH '$.percentage')) jt;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6ade7630b705a7c3408a4cf1dce550f0)